# Argument Out of Range Exception when Reading XML Attribute

Tags: c#, xml

I get the following error (I have a custom error console that reports my issues

```
  7:09:17 PM > # ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. 
  7:09:17 PM > # Parameter name: i
```

It results when I try to read the following "donator" attribute from the XML File `GemsCraftConfig.gc`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GemsCraft Donator="True" />
```

Here is the Code I'm using to perform the operation... It worked fine in Visual Basic, but when I put it through an online converter

```
   XmlTextReader Reader = new XmlTextReader("GemsCraftConfig.gc");
        string DonatorEnabled = Reader.GetAttribute(0);

            if (DonatorEnabled == "True")
            {
  //Code is cut off from here on
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using LinqToXml

```
bool donator = (bool)XDocument.Load("GemsCraftConfig.gc") 
                              .Root.Attribute("Donator");
```

Comment: how should I be able to get if it says "True" or "False" in the Donator attribute?

Comment: @user2678408 See the code again. it returns a boolean variable. `if(donator==true){......}`

Comment: @user2678408 thanks for very explanatory comment *"still got the error"*. What error do you get? What does the exception say? BTW: I tested it before posting. So it *does work* ...

Comment: Sorry I'm a noob :)  # ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values

Comment: @user2678408 As I said "it works". Unless you show how you use it, I can not say anything about it. BTW: there is no code to get `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` in my post. You propably get it somewhere else.

Comment: it says line 95 and line 95 is that If Statement in the code

Comment: @user2678408 I posted a **WORKING** code. buy it or not. BTW: I have no crystal ball to see your code at line 95. Good night.